# Ngrx subscribe is not firing in unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to write a unit test to verify what is done within a subscribe on a store slice. When I try manually the subscribe runs, but not in the unit test.

```
ngOnInit():void {
  this.currentPage$ = this.store.pipe(select('recipes'));

  this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    filter(params => 'pageId' in params),
    map(params => params.pageId),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
  ).subscribe(pageId => {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadPage(pageId, 5)); 
  });


  this.store.select(getAllRecipes).pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((recipes) => {
    if (recipes !== null) {
      this.recipes = recipes['recipes'];
      this.currentPage = Number(recipes['currentPage']);
      this.totalPages = Number(recipes['totalPages']);
    };
  });
}
```

the test:

```
fit('should load all recipes of the page indicated by the value of the url param pageId', fakeAsync(() => { 
  let getRecipesSpy = spyOn(RecipeService.prototype, 'getRecipes').and.returnValue([{id: 2, title: 'trololo', description: 'htotoa'}]);    
  mockActivatedRoute.testParams = {pageId: '3'};
  //await component.store.select(getAllRecipes).subscribe();
  //tick();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(getRecipesSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3);
  expect(component.recipes).toEqual([{id: 2, title: 'kjhkh', description: 'hahahoho'}]);
}));
```

Elsewhere in my code I got this working with:
`await component.currentPage$.subscribe();`

but this seems very unelegant to me. Is there a better way to ensure subscribes are firing?

thanks a lot for any help

Comment: you dispatched an action, so state changed, and your selector emits?

Comment: @enno void this.store.select(getAllRecipes).pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((recipes) => { does run in manual test, but not in unit test. I have come to think that this store selector does not work in test because I might not have setup the store correcty in the unit test, but I am not sure how to do it right. II need to explore that. Currently I have that :       imports: [ StoreModule.forRoot({currentPage: recipesReducer})

Comment: Also, in manual test the subscribe is firing twice. How to make the test wait for the second time ?

Comment: Where the store get filled? You also fill the store in your unit test?

Comment: it gets filled in the component, not in the unit test. I think you made me find one issue. in my app.module I had StoreModule.forRoot({ recipes: recipesReducer }), and in the test I had StoreModule.forRoot({currentPage: recipesReducer}). I made it be the same. Now I would like to await component.store.select(getAllRecipes); because otherwise the expects are running too early, but it says : Property 'store' is private and only accessible within class 'RecipesComponent'.

Comment: I also tried to make store public in the component and tried in the test: await component.store.select(getAllRecipes).pipe(skip(1)); but it does not seems to wait until the second time the subscribe fires

Comment: I think the issue is that when run outside a test, the store observable returns immediately with the initial value of the state at the time of subscription. This is why skip(1) is used in the first place.
But this doesnt seem to occur in unit tests, which is causing the issue.